# Alexa check if a new session was started by accessing session.new

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This is the data that is being send by alexa to my skills backend. In the backend code I would like to test if the session is new or not and based on this information I would like to produce a different output. I try to access the **session.new**, but I don't know how and I could now find anything about it online so far.

[image: This is the data that is being send by alexa to my skills backend]

```
const { attributesManager } = handlerInput;
const requestAttributes = attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
requestAttributes.session.new
//this leads to the error "cannot read property new of undefined"

const { attributesManager } = handlerInput;
const requestAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
sessionAttributes.session.new
//this leads to the same error
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that this is not possible using the AttributesManager because this only allows access to request, session and permanent attributes. But session.new is not part of those. If you want to check if the Alexa session is new you have to use the so called **RequestEnvelopeUtils**.
Using those you can access if the session is new or not by using the following statement.

**(Alexa.isNewSession(handlerInput.requestEnvelope))**